# Return Solr documents with maximum intersection in a multivalued field

Tags: solr

Consider the following solr document.

```
 {
     "id":"71850",
     "title":"Blah Blah Blah",
     "tags":["Lifestyle","Relationship","Social Wellness"],
     "_version_":1557041802828054529
  }
```

The document represents a blog post and a few tags associated with it.  The problem I am trying to solve is to get the most relevant documents to a given blog post based on maximum `tags` intersection.

Here `tags` is a multivalued field.

The documents having more intersection should be ordered higher in the result.For example the documents with `3 tag` matches should appear higher than the ones which have `2 tag` matches and so on.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried using [the MoreLikeThis functionality](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/MoreLikeThis) with the `tags` field as the `mlt.fl` value?

Comment: No I haven't tried it, will do now.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following query:

http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q="Lifestyle" "Relationship" "Social Wellness"&qf=tags

Maybe this fits your needs.

Best regards,
ewatch